# Strcpy parameters are not correct

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am updating an older visual studio project to VS2013 and keep running into an issue where it does not like the parameters that I pass into `strcpy` functions.
 This is a Unicode application.
I get the error -

> **cannot convert argument 2 from 'CString' to 'const char *'**

```
strcpy(szFileName, m_strFileName);
```

`m_strFileName` is defined as a `CString`.

Comment: You what to use the wide versions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx - wcscpy_s

Comment: check this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awkwbzyc.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strcpy` function accepts only parameters of type `char*`. That's what the compiler error is telling you—you have a type mismatch error. In a Windows environment, `char*` means *narrow* (*i.e.*, ANSI) strings. Which no one uses anymore and hasn't for well over a decade.

You know this already; you say that you're building a Unicode application, which is what you should be doing. But that means you can't call the narrow string functions (`str*`) anymore. You have two options. Either:

- Explicitly call the "wide" (*i.e.*, Unicode) variants of the C string library functions, which are prefixed with `wcs` instead of `str`. In this case, then, you'd be calling `wcscpy`.
- Use the macros that map automatically to the correct variant of the C string library functions. If the `_UNICODE` symbol is defined (as it would be for you), they will map to the wide-string variants; otherwise, they map to the narrow-string variants. These functions (actually macros) are all prefixed with `_tcs`. In this case, then, you'd call `_tcscpy`.

Comment: "Which no one uses anymore and hasn't for well over a decade." you would be surprised. :)